# How to count enums and group by date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has a date column and a user_type column. How do I get the count of user_type grouped by dates

Table- User_Date

```
Date         user_type
```

---

```
09/20/2020   Sales
09/20/2020   Sales
09/20/2020   Customer
09/20/2020   Customer
09/21/2020   Sales
09/21/2020   Customer
```

Desired result

```
Date        Customer Sales
09/20/2020   2         2
09/21/2020   1         1
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard SQL, you can use:

```
select date,
       sum(case when user_type = 'Sales' then 1 else 0 end) as sales,
       sum(case when user_type = 'Customer' then 1 else 0 end) as customer
from t
group by date;
```

This is standard syntax supported by virtually all databases.  Some databases have shortcuts.

In Postgres, I would phrase this as:

```
select date,
       count(*) filter (where user_type = 'Sales') as sales,
       count(*) filter (where user_type = 'Customer') as customer
from t
group by date;
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot Gordon.